# How to solve the logout issue Firebase FLutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I am making app in flutter. I have issue that when `User X loggedIn` into app with email and when `User X loggedOut` and immediately `User Y loggedIn` into app from same device (without killing the app), then app shows profile of `User X` even though `User Y` is logged in.

But when user kills the app and restart the app again then profile shows the data of correct user who is logged in.

I am using `Firebase` for backend activities.

My logout code is as follows:

```
logOutUser() async {
    await _auth.signOut();
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs?.clear();
    Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) =>
        LoginPage()), (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
}
```

In `Auth.dart` file:

```
Future signOut() async {
    try{
      return await _auth.signOut();
    } catch(e){
      print(e.toString());
      return null;
    }
  }
```

Is there any mistake in my logout code ? OR There should be some other reason?

Comment: I recommend that you watch these videos https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL4cUxeGkcC9j--TKIdkb3ISfRbJeJYQwC (videos 4-9)
P.S: I have no affiliation with "The Net Ninja" (Youtube channel)

Comment: @NishuthanS : I have done the same thing for login and logout as the videos you have provided. But the problem is as above I have explained. Should I update my question with more code which I have done as to see you for your reference?

Comment: @Harry have you found any solution?